# Fair value game to pay for dinner

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is a game I came up with to play with my girlfriend when we go out for dinner. The intent is to account for the price of what each of us orders. If we play this game together forever, the mean value for each of us should be 0. I know we can just pay for our own meals but that’s no fun .

I (person A) order a meal for \$10. She (person B) orders a meal for \$5. The total price is \$15. We then generate a random number from 1 to 15. If the number is between 1 and 10, I lose the game and have to pay the entire bill. If the number is between 11 and 15, she loses and she has to pay the entire bill.

**Option 1: Don’t play the game**

Each person pays for their own bill. Net value means paying for a meal and getting the value of the meal in return. I pay for a \$10 meal and get a meal worth \$10 in return. Net value is \$0.

> Expected value for A = (chance of winning/losing)(net value) = (1)(10-10) = 0

> Expected value for B = (chance of winning/losing)(net value) = (1)(5-5) = 0

**Option 2: Play the game**

> Expected value for A = (chance of losing)(net value) + (chance of winning)(net value) = (10\15)(-15+10) + (5/15)(+10) = 0

> Expected value for B = (chance of losing)(net value) + (chance of winning)(net value) = (5\15)(-15+5) + (10/15)(+5) = 0

This calculation makes perfect sense to me but everyone around me seems to think it’s wrong. They say it’s because of what I call net value. The value I receive for consuming the meal is not the same units as the money I pay for the meal and thus shouldn’t be included in the calculation. When they do this calculation, they get negative EV for both people, or positive for one and negative for the other. This intuitively makes no sense to me. Am I making a jump in logic? If I am, can you suggest a way to improve the game.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Whether the EV is positive or negative depends on the definition. If you define the money paid extra as negative and money saved as positive, you get your result: no one pays extra or saves money in the long run.

However, one may consider all money paid to be negative. In that case, the EV for both of you will be negative (as someone has to pay to bill eventually). We see that there is a $10/15$ and $5/15$ chance of $A$ or $B$ paying the whole bill of $\$15$. Therefore the EV of $A$ would be $-\$10$ and the EV of $B$ would be $-\$5$.

The above numbers are unequal, but the game is perfectly fair since $A$ should pay the bill of $\$10$ and $B$ their bill of $\$5$ anyways.